# emacs-org mode and html publishing: how to change structure of generated HTML

Tags: html, emacs, export, org-mode

I'm beginner to this so sorry if I overlook something simple...

I'd like to use emacs org-mode for my HTML pages. The 'default' setup is nice and working, however I'd like to use one of the free web templates, e.g. http://www.freecsstemplates.org/preview/goodlife/

These templates provide CSS files, however just usage of CSS in org-mode's HTML export seem not to be  enough. It seems that to use these templates correctly I need as well to maintain HTML structure as shown in such template.

How can I force org-mode to generate HTML structure I like (i.e. frame division)?

It seems, that some options are offered by 'org-export-generic.el'. Even if I would persuade generic export to provide me with a single HTML page, it still does not resolve completely the HTML export....

Answer (score 2):

This section of the org-mode manual provides some guidance on exporting to html and using css http://orgmode.org/manual/CSS-support.html#CSS-support  This includes a description of the default classes org-mode uses so you could modify your CSS.

If you want to modify org mode exports to match your CSS classes and ids use the :HTML_CONTAINER_CLASS: property in an org headline and the :CUSTOM_ID: property for creating ids.

Instead of setting things up per file I use org mode's publishing ability to output many org files into a single website.  You can find a tutorial on that here http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-publish-html-tutorial.html

My org-publish-project-alist looks like:

```
'(org-publish-project-alist (quote (("requirements" :components ("req-static" "req-org"))
   ("req-static" :base-directory "~/org/requirements" :publishing-directory "~/public_html/requirements/" :base-extension "gif\\|css" :publishing-function org-publish-attachment) 
   ("req-org" :base-directory "~/org/requirements/" :publishing-directory "~/public_html/requirements/" :style "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"./style.css\" />" :section-numbers nil :headline-levels 3 :table-of-contents 2 :auto-sitemap t :sitemap-filename "index.org" :sitemap-title "Requirements for My Software" :link-home "./index.html"))
```

Comment: that is not really my concern. The problem is, that org-mode does not allow you to put the org data into the structure of the HTML. CSS can change just the format of the fonts, but it cannot change the way HTML is generated

Answer (score 0):

I agree.  The HTML generated by org's built-in export is good but not quite what I'd want.  It appears that the generic export are based on elisp, whereas I prefer XSLT.

I wrote the following code for turning an org file into XML, but I haven't written the publishing transforms yet.  Anyway, this may be helpful for your reference, especially as it shows the structure of an org document's internal representation.

```
(require 'org-element)

(defvar xml-content-encode-map
  '((?& . "&amp;")
    (?< . "&lt;")
    (?> . "&gt;")))

(defvar xml-attribute-encode-map
  (cons '(?\" . "&quot;") xml-content-encode-map))

(defun write-xml (o out parents depth)
  "Writes O as XML to OUT, assuming that lists have a plist as
their second element (for representing attributes).  Skips basic
cycles (elements pointing to ancestor), and compound values for
attributes."
  (if (not (listp o))
      ;; TODO: this expression is repeated below
      (princ o (lambda (charcode)
                 (princ 
                  (or (aget xml-content-encode-map charcode)
                      (char-to-string charcode))
                  out)))

    (unless (member o parents)
      (let ((parents-and-self (cons o parents))
            (attributes (second o)))

        (dotimes (x depth) (princ "\t" out))
        (princ "<" out)
        (princ (car o) out)

        (loop for x on attributes by 'cddr do
              (let ((key (first x))
                    (value (second x)))

                (when (and value (not (listp value)))
                  (princ " " out)
                  (princ (substring (symbol-name key) 1) out)
                  (princ "=\"" out)
                  (princ value  (lambda (charcode)
                                  (princ 
                                   (or (aget xml-attribute-encode-map charcode)
                                       (char-to-string charcode))
                                   out)))
                  (princ "\"" out))))

        (princ ">\n" out)

        (loop for e in (cddr o)  do
              (write-xml e out parents-and-self (+ 1 depth)))

        (dotimes (x depth) (princ "\t" out))
        (princ "</" out)
        (princ (car o) out)
        (princ ">\n" out)))))

(defun org-file-to-xml (orgfile xmlfile)
  "Serialize ORGFILE file as XML to XMLFILE."
  (save-excursion
    (find-file orgfile)
    (let ((org-doc (org-element-parse-buffer)))
      (with-temp-file xmlfile
        (let ((buffer (current-buffer)))
          (princ "<?xml version='1.0'?>\n" buffer)
          (write-xml org-doc buffer () 0)
          (nxml-mode)))))
  (find-file xmlfile)
  (nxml-mode))

(defun org-to-xml ()
  "Export the current org file to XML and open in new buffer.
Does nothing if the current buffer is not in org-mode."
  (interactive)
  (when (eq major-mode 'org-mode)
    (org-file-to-xml
     (buffer-file-name)
     (concat (buffer-file-name) ".xml"))))
```

Comment: This seems as an interesting option: export data into XML and use a parser which would put the data into structure of mu choice (like python) :)